# How to manage thousands of Git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, repository, structure, product

I'm working for a company that develops a set of products, having each of them be composed by tens or even hundreds of components.

For the sake of good organization, security, maintainability and integration capabilities, we are planning to migrate from our old TFS server to a set of Git repositories. We have set two strategies that may work for us:

1. one repo per Product, having that every repo would store all the different components for that product, or
2. a more modular approach: one repo per component.

Option 2 is our favourite one, as it simplifies the management of triggers aimed to execute processes like release generation. Nonetheless, this approach introduces new challenges in our processes such as maintainability of such a bunch of repositories.

We are now in initial definition phase for this Git repositories integration, so we would like some feedback in order to determine which way to go.

Do you know about examples of companies (or even you yourselves) that use this approach with such amount of repositories and which good practices apply to them?

What challenges can be found in the use and management of these repositories?

From your experienced point of view, does this fine-grain component Git repos approach offer more pros than cons than the Product Git repository approach?

Thank you very much.

Best regards,
Roberto Rodríguez.

Comment: Here's [a blogpost from Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cse/2021/11/23/working-with-a-monorepo/) about their approach with monorepos

Comment: Some notes based on our tooling - https://worklifenotes.com/2021/11/10/monorepos-how-we-do-it-with-reliza-hub/